# SQL: Order on the basis of values of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that includes 3 columns - `chat, video, and call`. They can have values `0` or `1`.

Now I want to order results such that if all three (chat, video, and call) are `0`, then those rows are in the last else they have random order.

What will be the SQL query in this case? I am using MySQL.

Comment: Do you really need "random" order, or "any" order will suffice?

Comment: Random order is important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional ordering using a `CASE` clause in the `ORDER BY` clause.

For example:

```
select *
from t
order by case when chat + video + `call` = 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

If randon order is really important you can change the ordering as shown below:

```
select *
from t
order by case when chat + video + `call` = 0 
                 then 1 + rand() 
                 else 0 + rand() 
         end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just order them descending.
The (0,0,0) tupples stay at the bottom

```
select *
from yourtable
order by chat desc, video desc, `call` desc
```

But that sort them all.

But you can sort also by nulling the true OR's
*(since NULL stays on top when sorted ascending)*

```
select *
from yourtable
order by nullif(chat or video or `call`,1)
```

Comment: But in this case (1,1,1) will always remain on top

Comment: @TusharAgrawal Indeed, so added an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that column values can be only 0 or 1 and MySQL understands them in logical operations:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY CASE WHEN chat OR video OR call THEN RAND()+1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```